# I do not understand some of the decisions made regarding content deletion that, in my view, appear arbitrary

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

Is there a way to report a moderator who appears to abuse his/her powers?
How can a user make sure a moderator is not abusing his/her powers or understand why the aforementioned moderator is not doing so?

These are the facts:
This recent [post](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/13743/how-do-i-tell-a-woman-that-her-pants-have-a-menstruation-stain) has had several replies

The top reply had a comment mentioning that the post may be improved by not suggesting to write to the person because written comments may have a stronger impact and be more embarrassing. It was also suggesting that by doing it "not face-to-face" may have the opposite effect of implying that there is a bigger problem. This comment was up-voted by about 20 people (which, in this context, is a high number).
It appears that a new comment was added that replies to it, but the comment it replies to was deleted.

That was a comment relating to the question and it was suggesting (possibly wrongly, of course, it is a matter of opinion) a way to improve it.

In addition, the user who wrote the answer and who wrote the comment answering the previous "suggestion for an improvement" writes a comment that appears to be upset, annoyed at the criticism, and even a little polemical (at least it appears so, in my opinion).

The deleted comment is similar to another comment that says: *This has the disadvantage of involving yet another party, though. Depending on the person, mightn't that make it even more embarrassing?* 
However, that comment was made on a different answer, and it was not removed, though it was essentially the same (it pointed to a problem with the approach in the answer, one can disagree with it, but it has its merits).

I have seen other comments on answers by the same user removed, which is why I am asking this question.

I hope this is clear, please ask for clarification if it is not. Thank you!

Comment: Ideally, you would ask a question on meta about the action; if you'd like, you could turn this question into one. If you do, please be specific about what happened and why you think the moderator's action was incorrect. We're happy to help.

Comment: In addition to what HDE said, please do understand that this site has a very, very strict comment policy. We are acting based on the directions of our users in removing chatty, unnecessary, and argumentative comments from posts.

Comment: @HDE226868 Thank you. I was trying to understand how to do that? Should I mention the moderator? I was not sure whether that would appear rude

Comment: Didn't you already ask a question about [why your comments were being removed](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/how-do-i-know-who-deleted-my-comments)?

Comment: @sphennings This is something completely different

Comment: It seems to me like you're still asking "How can I determine how a comment of mine was deleted?"

Comment: @sphennings It seems you are trying to judge my post before I even post it

Comment: @user I would arrange it along the lines of "Here's the content: [Content]. Here's what action a moderator took: [Description]. Here's why I think that action was wrong: [Rationale]." I would advise checking previous meta discussions first, though, in case this sort of situation has already been discussed.

Comment: @HDE226868 Thank you for your reply, you are always very helpful and trying to help

Comment: It is funny someone already downvoted a question that was just asking for information. People should really read: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change

Comment: If I can maybe make one more suggestion: Your meta posts are both along the lines of "How can I deal with someone who wronged me?" Perhaps in the future, it might be more productive to ask "Why was [moderation action X] taken against my content?" Maybe it's just a superficial change, but it does mean taking a more positive view of the situation - not assuming that the other person's in the wrong.

Comment: @HDE226868 I am happy to retitle the question any way you want, I have no problem with that if it sounds rude the way it is. I thought that the content was quite neutral, but I do think there is a problem, I cannot change that

Comment: Welcome to the club. Lots of users here don't agree with what is happening. And many give up using IPS. Some do it silently, some with parting shots. Just have a look at recent other Meat posts. But the moderators insist they are right...

Answer (score 12):

I was the moderator who deleted your comment. In full, it read

> I think the use of IM is not a very good suggestion. People get much more embarrassed having to reply in writing (or even to be told something in writing). I also think the "not face-to-face is not good", it really implies there is something wrong.

The reasons for deletion are basically the same as [elaborated upon in response to a previous meta question of yours](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2833/102):

- We have a strict comments policy here because of the subject matter we deal with on the site, and the importance of serious, well thought-out suggestions.
- Comments should only be used to request clarifications or suggest improvements, which is why we 're currently running [an experiment](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2839/102) to change the wording on the "comment" prompt.
- Your comment expressed your disagreement with the answer. It doesn't matter if you agree or disagree: the comment will get deleted because it doesn't add anything. If you disagree that much, write your own answer.

There are some other things worth noting. First, you'd previously written a comment similar to that under the answer, and it was deleted by another mod; you then rewrote the comment and posted it in the form I quoted above. Second, I don't think that the answerer's tone in their comment was particularly upset; if it was, it might be because they'd already gotten half a dozen comments on their answer expressing agreement or disagreement . . . and that's half a dozen too much.

On a final note, a member of the community flagged the comment before I got to it, so this wasn't moderator action coming out of nowhere.

Comment: About 20 people had up-voted that comment. In addition, how is that comment different than the one I quoted? You do not find Cascabel comment polemical, I find it quite so, how can you leave that one and delete the comment it replies to? I think this site (IPS) is by far the most unfriendly of all, I never dealt in any other SE site with so many unreasonable mods (actually, with no-one), tbh, and I belong to more than a dozen.

Comment: Is there a forum where I can suggest that IPS should be changed in the way it works? It is really an unfriendly place, and being a member of the SE community for many years, it really bothers me.

Comment: @user 16 people upvoted it, and, well, [you can't downvote comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3615/274942). Plus, the question's gotten thousands of views, and it's certain that people must disagree with it. Finally, votes were never, are not, and will never be a factor when it comes to decisions of moderation. That's not how it works. Also, Cascabel's comment was left as a preventative measure, in the hopes of reducing the number of future unnecessary comments on the post.

Comment: Feel free to use the contact button at the bottom of any page if you have any concerns. But, be advised, the CMs (Community Managers - the ones who will receive your message) are the ones who started us on this path.

Comment: @HDE It seems you are not even going to ever admit you made a mistake, and this is a problem with IPS that does not exist in any other SE site

Comment: @Catija I like the path, I do not like the attitude. The recent blog post seems to be wanting to go exactly in the opposite direction

Comment: If you want a second opinion, I agree with HDE that your comment failed to meet our comment policy's requirements. I would also have deleted your comment. @user As the comment Cascabel left says, if you have a differing opinion, that's the time to write another answer, not to criticize the top-scoring answer.

Comment: @Catija Of course, it is so different than the other one that was posted :)