# Why can't I add comments?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, comments

I answered [this](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/13743/how-do-i-tell-a-woman-that-her-pants-have-a-menstruation-stain) question. 
I also wanted to add a comment on another one, but I am unable to do so. Why?

EDIT:
The problem is I do not see the usual add comment link, I only see suggest improvements

[image]

Comment: Are you getting an error saying that you can't? Can you tell us more about what you see what you try to post a comment (maybe a screenshot)?

Comment: @HDE226868  I do not see the add comment link, I only see suggest improvements

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We are currently doing [an experiment](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2839/102) where users are encouraged to suggest improvements, rather than leave comments. Comments on this site work differently than others. They are supposed to be only for suggesting improvements or requesting clarification.

We are trying to see if by making the text say "suggest improvements" rather than "add a comment" we would get more productive and less chatty comments. The functionality is exactly the same.

Comment: @sphenning Thank you. It was confusing because I see add comments everywhere else, still.

Comment: Perhaps we should make this question featured to prevent further confusion from other users unaware that the experiment is going on.

Comment: @Thunderforge Not necessary. That'd make our experiment futile.